# How can I upgrade to Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS from 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with an old disc and update it.
How can I get the new 12.04.4 LTS.

Comment: Open a terminal and try `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have applied all updates, through partial upgrade or not, you should have 12.04.4. Marc already said the commands you need:

```
sudo apt-get update # will fetch you new packages info
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade # will agressively upgrade all packages
```

After that, just remove old kernels and packages' config through Synaptic or Aptitude.

Comment: How can I  remove old kernels and packages' config through Synaptic or Aptitude. Can you explain.?

Comment: Open Synaptic and search for 3.2.0 inside Installed packages then remove kernel and headers with less release number. For example, you will find 3.2.0-15 and 3.2.0-37, you should remove first.

Comment: And for config just open not installed (has configuration files), select all and remove totally.

Comment: Well for the sake of absolute beginner can you explain where I find the synaptic and config..? As I said I just Migrated from Windows. If you can help me its worth learning.

Comment: OK. For Synaptic, open Terminal and write `sudo apt-get install synaptic`. Then open Dash and write Synaptic. There you will see five buttons on the left down corner and search field on top. Select the second button, which will lead you to the _State_ tools. Then you can select installed packages and search for kernel. But it is recommended not to hurry up. Just play with interface and try to understand the package structure and principles.

Comment: I just got this  `uname -a`  `Linux vipin-Satellite-C640 3.11.0-18-generic #32~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Feb 20 17:54:21 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux`. Hope all is well. Isn't it.?